# ¿Como puedo iterar un datatable con los meses del año en Jsf?

Tags: jsf

La situacion es que tengo un datatable en la que debo mostrar el rendimiento mensual de un punto de venta discriminandolo mes a mes.

Estructura:
Punto de venta|Enero|Febrero|....
Tienda 1        20    15     ....

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar necesitas una estructura que almacene los nombres de los meses para el encabezado de la tabla.

Imagino que es anual o a lo sumo los meses son variables.

Para esto puedes simplemente definirte una lista de elementos de tipo `String`con los meses.

```
List<String> nombresMeses = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Para obtener los nombres de los meses puedes basarte en el siguiente metodo. Dado un entero retorna el nombre del mes. Es importante que tengas seteado la locacion correcta en Locale.

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
public String getMonth(int month) {
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
}
```

Esta implementacion es interesante si tenes un numero variable de meses, si siempre estas mostrando la anualidad puedes simplemente cargar manualmente el array con los nombres de los meses.

Ahora bien, necesitas otra estructura que almacene para cada Punto de Venta el rendimiento mensual. Asumo que dispones del rendimiento mensual y que se trata de un `int/double`o algún otro tipo primitivo.

Resulta útil en estos casos utilizar una implementacion de la interfaz Map 
(por ejemplo HashMap, donde no se permiten claves duplicadas), donde para cada clave dispones de 0 o más valores. Para este caso la clave seria el nombre del mes y el valor corresponde al rendimiento del punto de venta.

La estructura, a groso modo sería:

```
Class PuntoDeVenta
    String idPuntoDeVenta;
    //Map<K,V> K: Nombre del mes, V: rendimiento del punto de venta para el mes 
    Map<String, Double> rendimientoPorMesMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

Luego, en tu controlador de Puntos de Venta, defines:

```
Class PuntoDeVentaController
   List<PuntoDeVenta> puntosDeVenta;
```

Y en tu HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml""
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    >
                <h:dataTable id="table" value="#{puntoDeVentaController.puntosDeVenta}" var="item">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:columnGroup styleClass="rich-sdt-header-cell">
                                <h:column rowspan="2">
                                    <h:outputText value="" />
                                </h:column>
                                <!--Llenar encabezado con lista de nombres de meses-->
                                <c:forEach items="#{puntoDeVentaController.nombresMeses}" var="mes">
                                    <rich:column colspan="2" rowspan="1" >
                                        <h:outputText value="#{mes}"/>
                                    </rich:column>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </rich:columnGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                        <!--Columna para indicar el punto de venta por su ID-->
                        <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.idPuntoDeVenta}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <!--Llenado de los 'rendimientos' a traves de acceder al map con el mes como clave -->
                        <c:forEach items="#{puntoDeVentaController.nombreMeses}" var="mes">
                                    <rich:column>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{item.rendimientoPorMesMap.get(mes)}">
                                        </h:outputText>
                                    </rich:column>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <f:facet name="footer" style="padding-top:5px;">
                            <!--En el footer podrias agregar 'totales' por mes -->
                        </f:facet>
                </h:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier cosa a las ordenes!

Comment: hola muchas gracias por responder, estoy intentando hacerlo como dices pero sinceramente y honestamente se me a dificultado la implementacion de ` Map<String, Double> rendimientoPorMesMap = new HashTable<String, Double>();`.  Como hago para que funcione.Gracias

Comment: Disculpa, habia un error en la respuesta, utiliza HashMap no Hashtable.
Es necesario que importes java.util.Map y java.util.HashMap. Luego simplemente tienes que cargar la estructura con los valores que correspondan, por ej: Map<String, Double> rendimientoPorMesMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
   rendimientoPorMesMap.put("Enero 2016", 212.22);
   rendimientoPorMesMap.put("Febrero 2016", 512.32);